# Как можно перебрать определенную колонку в цикле?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных

Имеем DataFrame:

```
Unnamed: 0 FUL MAIL DRT RUM dt
4 4 Иванов5 admin@tt.ru 1.05 3 2020-05-01
5 6 Иванов7 tempa@tt.com 5.08 4 2020-08-05
```

Мне надо, пройтись по значениям колонки `MAIL` и подставить в адрес получателя.

То есть, в `mailto: $mail` подставить все значения из колонки `MAIL` по одному.

Comment: Что значит подставить по одному? Какую строку или строки вы хотите составить? Какой результат должен быть для указанных в вопросе двух мейлов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов:

1.

```
for row in df.itertuples():
    print(row[4])
```

```
admin@tt.ru
tempa@tt.com
```

2.

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row[3])
```

```
admin@tt.ru
tempa@tt.com
```

3.

```
for addr in df["MAIL"].to_list():
    print(addr)
```

```
admin@tt.ru
tempa@tt.com
```

4й вариант - использовать метод apply к серии, но я бы не советовал так делать, поскольку это неканоническое использование метода, и вообще, так делать не следует.

Comment: А я бы не советовал использовать `iter` методы, они очень медленные )  Не надо приучать людей к плохому

Comment: Я бы тоже. Но, поскольку указанные методы не являются depricated, они имеют право быть перечисленными.

Answer (score 2):

Если вопрос в том, как пройтись циклом по значениям `pandas.Series`, то здесь даже выдумывать ничего не нужно, т.к. `Series` является *итерируемым* объектом:

```
for x in df["MAIL"]:
    print(x)
```

Если же суть вопроса в том, как сформировать одну строку (например список отправки `BCC`) сразу со всеми адресами эл. почты, разделенными запятой или точкой с запятой, то стоит уточнить вопрос и привести пример ожидаемого результата.